# Is $R\otimes_K K \cong R$ if $R$ is a $K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can we claim that $R\otimes_K K \cong R$ if $R$ is a $K$-algebra (with $K$ a commutative ring)？（this holds true when treating $\Bbb{C}$ as a $\Bbb{R}$-algebra correct? ) Is it true that $R\otimes_R K \cong K$ if $R$ is supplemented? Can we say $K$ is projective $R-$module?

Sorry for the silly question. The idea to prove the isomorphism as above is using the universal property, However, I don't really know how to implement it.

Comment: When you write $A \otimes_C B$, $A$ and $B$ need to be $C$-modules. So when you write $R \otimes_R K$ there needs to be an $R$-module structure on $K$.

Comment: The $R$ has a $K$ module structure given by $f(k)r = k\cdot r$, however I don't know how to give $R$ module structure on $K$ is it because the supplemented condition provide a $K$ algebra homoromophism $\epsilon:R\to K$? @Trevor Gunn

Comment: what statement above is correct?

Comment: It is true that $R \otimes_K K \cong R$ for any $K$-module $R$.

Comment: Yeah I have proved this but mislead by your comment Do $K$ has $R$ module structure?@Zhen Lin